# Why are all materials pink in my Unity URP project?

Tags: unity, materials, unity-urp

Version: Unity 2020.2.0f1

I started my project with Universal Render Pipeline template but I don't know why all materials are pink. I even tried to upgrading but nothing happened.

This error was coming after upgrading:
[image]

And when I am creating new materials then I still getting pink materials and I am also not able to upgrade them:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To upgrade built-in Shaders ([ref](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/upgrading-your-shaders.html)):

> Open your Project in Unity, and go to **Edit** > **Render Pipeline** >
> **Universal Render Pipeline**. According to your needs, select either **Upgrade Project Materials to URP Materials or Upgrade Selected**
> Materials to URP Materials.

Comment: I got `TrailFollowMaterial material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert Legacy Shaders/Particles/~Additive-Multiply shader to selected pipeline
UnityEditor.Rendering.Universal.UniversalRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader:UpgradeProjectMaterials() (at`

Answer (score 1):

A way I've managed to fix this is by right-clicking on the Project then selecting "Reimport all".

Answer (score 1):

In addtion to what has being said, you might check if there is indeed a Render Pipeline selected in your project.

Go to **Edit > Project Settings > Graphics**

Check if **Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings** is not marked as **None**.

If it is **None** you'll certainly experience pink materials.

[image: Scriptable Render Pipeline Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it; just downgrade your URP from 12.0 to an older version.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it explained how to perform the downgrade, and which version worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a URP asset. To do so, right click in the project window and choose create/Rendering/URP asset. Then make sure that this asset is set to your scriptable render pipeline setting. (check Edit/Project settings/Scriptable Render Pipeline Setting). on the final steps, you can Upgrade your materials by going to Edit/Render Pipeline/Universal Render Pipeline/Upgrade.